# Subtyping using ssreflect

Tags: coq, subtype, ssreflect

I have been trying to learn how to do subtyping using ssreflect, http://ssr.msr-inria.inria.fr/~jenkins/current/mathcomp.ssreflect.eqtype.html as my main reference, but have been running into problems. What I'm trying to do is from a type `T` with three terms, create a subtype `T'` with two terms `a,b`.
(1) what is the difference between `{x:T | P x}` and `subType P`?
(2) From my code below, I have `Sub a Pa` to be a term of `T'`, is it possible to have a general proof that applies for both `a, b`? I'm confused here as from `eqType.v` it feels as though `insub` is the one to be used to project from a type into its subtype.

```
From mathcomp Require Import ssreflect ssrfun ssrbool eqtype.

Inductive T : Set := a | b | c.

Definition P := fun (x:T) =>
 match x with
 | a => true
 | b => true
 | c => false
 end.

 Definition T' := {x:T | P x}.
 Definition T'' := subType P.

 Definition cast (x: T) : option T'.
 destruct (P x) eqn:prf.
 - exact (Some (exist _ x prf)).
 - exact None.
 Defined.


 Definition Pa : is_true (P a).
   destruct (P a) eqn:prf.
   exact. simpl in prf. unfold is_true. symmetry. apply prf. Defined.

 Check (Sub a Pa) : T'.

 Check val (Sub a Pa) : T.

 Check insub (val (Sub a Pa)) : option T'.

 Definition Px :forall x : T, is_true (P x).
  intros x. destruct (P x) eqn:prf.
  - unfold is_true. reflexivity.
  - unfold is_true.
  Abort.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> (1) what is the difference between {x:T | P x} and subType P?

`subType P` is a record containing all the relevant proofs for `P` to establish a subType of some types `val : U -> T`.

`{x : T | P x}` is a regular sigma type, and if `P` is a boolean predicate math-comp has declared a canonical way of building the `subType P` record for that type.

> (2) From my code below, I have Sub a Pa to be a term of T', is it possible to
>   have a general proof that applies for both a, b? I'm confused here as
>   from eqType.v it feels as though insub is the one to be used to
>   project from a type into its subtype.

I am unsure about what you mean. `insub` does not "project" but tries to embed [which is not always possible]. In your case, the proof is easy enough, and you don't have to complicate things so much:

```
From mathcomp Require Import all_ssreflect.

Set Implicit Arguments.
Unset Strict Implicit.
Unset Printing Implicit Defensive.

Inductive T : Set := a | b | c.

Definition is_ab (x:T) : bool := match x with
 | a | b => true
 | c => false
 end.

Definition abT := { x : T | is_ab x }.

Lemma abT_is_ab (x : abT) : is_ab (val x).
Proof. exact: valP. Qed.
```

Comment: My understanding of `insub` is for `x : T`, `insub x : abT` since it is a generic partial projection of `T` into a subtype `S` of `T`, and similarly for `x : abT`, we will have `val x : T`. Can you also further explain the lemma `abT_is_ab` and how it is used?

Comment: The lemma `abT_is_ab` is just an alias for `valP`, that is to say, that every element of the subtype satisfies the `P` predicate. The proof is trivial and amounts to destructing the record, would we have better support for primitive projections in math-comp `valP` would hold definitionally. `insub x` just checks if an element `x` is in the subtype. It amounts to checking the result of `P x`. **Note that** `insub x : option abT`, as it is not the case that any element `x : T` meets the `ab` predicate.